# What couses Could not load the default credentials error?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_u6P5k0vP0) tutorial.

I have this cloud function deployed with `firebase serve`:

```
exports.createScream = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const newScream = {
        body: req.body.body,
        userHandle: req.body.userHandle,
        createdAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
    };

    admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('screams')
        .add(newScream)
        .then((doc) => {
            res.json({ message: `document ${doc.id} created sucseccfully` });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).json({ error: err });
            console.error(err);
        });
});
```

I'm getting this error:

```
functions: Beginning execution of "createScream"
  Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
      at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync (C:\Users\Örs\Desktop\social-app\screem-app_functions\functions\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\googleauth.js:161:19)
     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
i  functions: Finished "createScream" in ~1s
```

What did I mess up? How do I fix it? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please post an issue on the firebase-tools GitHub with the steps to reproduce.  It sounds like it might actually be a duplicate.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: What do you mean by that? I'm so confused... Please help me

Comment: Follow the link I provided.  File an issue using the issues tab.

Comment: I tried my best, but with my limited English skills, I did not find, what couses my issue. :(

Comment: Please help me...